# Serial port communication and web application

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, serial-port

I need to integrate my REST (Jersey) and serial port communication. I have now problem with handling server actions. Basically I am using the RXTXcomm.jar library and open port directly in (parameters for serial port are hardcoded):

```
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
      public ApplicationConfig () {
            // init serial port here
      }
}
```

My problems:

1. The init class is instantiated with first call to my API. Can I somehow force the initialization earlier just after server start?
2. Second is port closing. When I stop the server I need to close my port. How to detect server stop event?
3. Do you see some problems with this approach? (this is optional question).

Thanks.

---

I don't want to pass a data via HTTP requests. Just use some parameter, and later fill serial data internally inside REST resource. Request will be very rare and from one 'client' only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) you can initialize your init class just as the server starts.

1. `ServletContextListener` has a `contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)` method which gets called when the server starts, which you can override to initialize your init class.
2. `ServletContextListener` has a `contextDestroyed(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)` which gets called when the server stops, and you can override it to close your port.
3. Yours seems like a hobby project, so I would suggest you to make it work first, and think about optimizing / cleansing later.

Comment: This is more like demo/trial project. I run your suggestion. For one START/STOP cycle works just fine. But when re-deploy my application I see exception: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library rxtxSerial.dll already loaded in another classloader thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver`.

Comment: You might want to stop/start your server instead of just redeploying. And if you don't want to do that, posting your code might help us debug.

Comment: You can also wrap the `System.load()` call with try/ catch while catching `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Comment: Many thanks! Your solution is perfect for normal work: one cycle start/stop server. I just post the error for reference (I observed because I have enabled "deploy on save" in IDE).

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine there could be a potential problem, if second request is made while the first is still writting to the serial port.

You could create a standalone application that would receive data over tcp/ip (or named pipes   or other means of ipc), buffer it in queue and send it forward to serial port.

Comment: Thanks for input. My request will be very rare and only from one 'client'. I don't want to use very complex solutions because of no time for this. But I think I understand your point. It could be nice solution.